# Draw expand/collapse buttons (+/-) when Aero is off

Tags: winforms, gdi+

With visual styles, i can use

```
VisualStyleElement.TreeView.Glyph.Closed
```

and **VisualStyleRenderer** to draw **[+] button** like in TreeView.

But when user have a "**Classic**" style in Windows, visual styles are not supported and I still need to draw this glyph.

It is still possible to use classes like

```
System.Windows.Forms.CheckBoxRenderer
```

but I haven't found anything like this for TreeView glyphs.

Comment: MS uses custom painting to draw this glyph in PropertyGrid, so it seems it is not possible to draw native +/- glyph when visual styles are off.

Comment: How did you managed to use VSE.TreeView.Glyph.Closed to draw glyph? .NET always refused to draw it with a message, that current theme does not support this part and eventually I had to wrap UXTheme on my own to do it.

Comment: I didn't. I dug into the .NET Framework Reference Source Code and found method **System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGridInternal.PaintOutline(Graphics, Rectangle)** which does the drawing of the expand button glyph in PropertyGrid. This is necessary when VisualStyleRenderer.IsSupported or VisualStyleRenderer.IsElementDefined returns false.

Comment: @Libor to be exact, **PaintOutline** is a method in **System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGridInternal.GridEntry** class located in **System.Windows.Forms.dll**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is not possible to get that glyph.  It is a simple one but you have to write the code.  DrawRectangle and DrawLine.  Or use a bitmap.  Or make it look like the simple Vista triangles.  Or don't enable ownerdraw when visual styles are off.